# Do not show jQuery UI Autocomplete when typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the jQuery UI Auto-complete functionality to show an auto-complete on a text input. I want more fidelity as to when the list appears. I have made triggers for Click and Double Click which show the auto-complete (based on if the user chooses to include each trigger) but I have found no way to affect whether or not the auto-complete shows up when typing.

How do I make it that auto-complete does not show when typing (not triggered by key events)?

**Answer**

```
function InitialiseAutoCompleteEx(inputId, trigOnClick, trigOnDoubleClick, trigOnType, trigOnCtrlSpace, rawAutoCompleteItems)
{
    var autoCompleteItems = rawAutoCompleteItems.split("|");
    var input = $("#" + inputId);

    input.autocomplete(
        {
            source: autoCompleteItems,
            minLength: 0,
            disabled: true,
            close: function() { $(this).autocomplete("option", "disabled", true); }
        });

    if (trigOnClick)
    {
        input.click(function()
            {
                $(this).autocomplete("option", "disabled", false);
                $(this).autocomplete("search");
            });
    }

    if (trigOnDoubleClick)
    {
        input.dblclick(function()
            {
                $(this).autocomplete("option", "disabled", false);
                $(this).autocomplete("search");
            });
    }

    if (trigOnType)
    {
        input.keydown(function(event)
            {
                var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);

                if ( /[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(key) )
                {
                    $(this).autocomplete("option", "disabled", false);
                    $(this).autocomplete("search");
                }
            });
    }

    if (trigOnCtrlSpace)
    {
        input.keydown(function(event)
            {
                if (event.which == 32 && event.ctrlKey)
                {
                    $(this).autocomplete("option", "disabled", false);
                    $(this).autocomplete("search");
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use its [`disabled` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-disabled):

```
$("#field").autocomplete("option", "disabled", true);
```

```js
var tags = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"];
$("#field").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
    response($.grep(tags, function(item) {
      return matcher.test(item);
    }));
  },
  disabled: true,
});

function disable(shouldDisable) {
  shouldDisable = JSON.parse(shouldDisable); // Extract boolean from string parameter
  $("#field").autocomplete("option", "disabled", shouldDisable);
  $("#field").focus().trigger($.Event("keydown"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="field" />
<button onclick="disable(false);">Autocomplete On</button>
<button onclick="disable(true);">Autocomplete Off</button>
```

Comment: And then re-enable when I want to trigger and disable whenever it gets closed?

Comment: @MrUniverse Disable it initially, but enable it when they ask for autocomplete. Unless I misunderstood your intent, and that's not what you want at all.

Comment: Just what I needed. Never thought to disable auto complete to block it's trigger events. I included the code working as I wanted included in question. Thanks!